# Why is this community so hostile?

Tags: discussion

[What are easiest areas to get away with lying on your resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/152315/what-are-easiest-areas-to-get-away-with-lying-on-your-resume)

Comment: A lot of the primary contributors here are hiring managers whose job it is to catch people who lie on their resumes. So, asking a question like this on here is kind of like walking into a police station and asking how to get away with murder.

Comment: Why Hostile? I even took the time to answer and edit your question, as other users also did. There is no hostile comments I can see... do you say it's hostile because your post got closed? That does not make the community hostile

Comment: @AffableAmbler Maybe I'm an optimist, but I would *hope* that even people who aren't hiring managers would agree that deliberately lying on your resume is not acceptable. If anything, those who are job seekers themselves should be highly motivated to not answer the question the OP linked to. Do you want a fair fight, where everyone tells the truth? Or do you want to give your competition advice on how to cheat the system and outperform you?

Answer (score 8):

You seem to think that getting a job is enough, and lying is fine if it helps you get a job.  But most people don't consider lying a good long term strategy, partly because keeping a job is just as important as getting one, and being able to get the next job as well.

If you get a job by lying, you'll likely be fired, and the next job will be even harder to get.  So giving advice on how to destroy your career is not what we do, and **discouraging you from destroying your career is not hostile**.  It's meant to be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I responded to your initial question. To be frank, I believe it's due to the wording of your question.

Here, we're honor-bound to try to get you an answer without letting our personal beliefs cloud our judgment.. too much.

It was definitely not a popular question you asked, but you know, I think we all deserve a little bit of help. I don't agree with the people who perform direct attacks against your character since that ain't productive.

I don't think we're all that hostile. Generalizing the community as hostile is a tad bit too far.

But on that same token, you have to consider the consequences of asking a question like that and anticipate how people are going to respond, right?

Comment: One can not be honor bound to do something that is not honorable.  Lying on a resume is neither honorable, nor a good idea

Answer (score 4):

First off, asking for anything unethical will be met with strong rebukes, in the very least.  This wasn't hostility any more than it's hostility to yell at a child who is about to run into traffic.

People were trying to warn you against a foolish act.  It's wrong to lie on a resume, plain and simple.  If that's not enough reason alone, then the **CONSEQUENCES** of lying should get your attention, which include, but are not limited to...

- Fired, if caught
- Being placed in a job you cannot do
- Getting fired from **ANOTHER** job
- Getting a reputation as a liar/con artist
- Getting a reputation as incompetent.

Oh, there's more.  But asking questions on how to do anything unethical or illegal are not going to go far here.

Answer (score 3):

Reading your question it sounds like what you're trying to say is that you held a job and you were let go. You were unable to contribute anything to that job, for various reasons. With that in mind, you would like to polish up your resume such that it is attractive but at the same time since you contributed nothing in your previous job, you want to know the extent of which a future employer would check into your past employment.

With that in mind, I think had you worded the question as such, you'd get better answers. With your current wording, you want to deceive your future employer and want to know how much you can get away with. To me I don't think anyone would agree to aid you in lying or get "insider tips" on what you can get away with.

It's sort of like going to a lawyer and asking to what extent could a person get away with a crime. It's not going to come across as something they'd want to assist you with.